# With PowerShell, is there a way to make an external hard disk attached to host available to VM?

Tags: powershell, windows-8, hyper-v

I have Hyper-V module installed but don't know what cmdlet to use. I've seen blogs showing how to do this using Hyper-V Manager. I have added a VHDx disk image with following cmdlet:

```
Add-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName MyWin7PC -ControllerType IDE -ControllerNumber 0 `
  -ControllerLocation 0 -Path "C:\Virtual Hard Disks\VDisk.MyWin7PC.Vhdx"
```

What I now need is a way for VM to have another drive E: which will show files and folders the host has on its G: drive (which is physically connected to a USB hard disk). I need this temporarily to install applications from the USB hard disk. You can do this using the Hyper-V Manager GUI.

Comment: To do *which* "same"? What problem are you trying to solve? What have you tried? And how were the results different from what you expected?

Comment: Host: Windows 8 with Hyper-V 
VM: Windows 7 Ultimate

C: drive on VM is a VHDX file on host, added with following cmdlet run from host.
Add-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName MyWin7PC -ControllerType IDE -ControllerNumber 0 -ControllerLocation 0 -Path "C:\Virtual Hard Disks\VDisk.MyWin7PC.Vhdx"

What I now need is a way for VM to have another drive E: which will show files and folders the host has on its G: drive (which is physically connected to a USB hard disk). I need this temporarily to install applications from the USB hard disk.

You can do this using the Hyper-V Manager GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Win8, so this is entirely untested. Judging from the description of [`Add-VMHardDiskDrive`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848470.aspx) something like this might work, though:

```
$usbdisk = gwmi Win32_DiskDrive | ? { $_.PNPDeviceID -like 'USBSTOR\*' }

Add-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName MyWin7PC -ControllerType IDE -ControllerNumber 0 `
  -ControllerLocation 1 -DiskNumber $usbdisk.Index
```

Comment: The parameter is not valid. The provided hard disk identifier is not either a vhd file path or a valid identifier of a 
physical hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make this disk Offliine. Try this:

```
"select disk 1","offline disk" | diskpart
```

Where 1 is your USB HD id. And then use `Add-VMHardDiskDrive`. If you want to do this when VM is online you must use SCSI Controller in VM.